# Craft CMS Backup DB

Tags: assets, database

Hey so I am quite new to Craft CMS & this might be a dumb question so please bear with me. I know that I can manually backup my database at any given point by going into Settings and Backup Database.

I have created a lot of different sub folders for the assets to help create organizing and separate certain content. Is this also being backed-up when I back-up the DB?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

The database backup will only backup the tables within your database, which does include references to your assets; such as their title, filename etc. However, the asset files themselves will not be included in the backup.

Most hosting providers will allow you to backup your filesystem. If yours doesn't, there are third-party services that can handle scheduled backups for you or you could write your own backup script that creates copies of your assets in another location.

Answer (score 3):

The assets themselves are not included in the backup. But if you have added assets into those directories, the paths to them are saved in the database and will therefore be included in the backup.

Answer (score 2):

Craft doesn't backup the file system but it's not hard to setup a cron on your server to do a backup periodically.

Throw this in a crontab (`crontab -e` on most systems):

```
30 2 * * * /bin/tar -czf /path/to/backup/location/backup.tar.gz /path/to/craft/
```

That'll backup every night at 2:30 am.

If you want to get even craftier, you might want to [`rsync`](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-off-site-backup-of-your-site-with-rsync-on-centos-6) the file to a another server, for example.

As [Scott](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/16084/1016) mentions in his answer, if you use something like Linode or Digital Ocean, you might consider using their backup services as well. I haven't used DO's but Linode has worked well for us for years.